# Nullable Reference Types and Either Pattern

Tags: c#, nullable, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I'm trying out the new [Nullable Reference Types in C# 8.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-out-nullable-reference-types/), and I'm facing the following issue.

Given this struct:

```cs
public readonly struct Either<TReturn, TError>
    where TReturn : struct
    where TError : struct
{
    public TError? Error { get; }
    public TReturn? Response { get; }

    public Either(TError? error, TReturn? response)
    {
        if (error == null && response == null)
        {
           throw new ArgumentException("One argument needs not to be null.");
        }
        if (error != null && response != null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("One argument must be null.");
        }
        Error = error;
        Response = response;
    }
}
```

How can I tell the compiler that *either* `Error` *or* `Response` is not null, and that they can't *both* be null? Is there a way to do such a thing with the new attributes?

Comment: `Either` has nothing to do with NRTs and that's not exactly an `Either` - it's just one type instead of two. The most relevant feature right now is switch expressions and pattern matching. eg `result switch { OK<TReturn> response=>...,Error<TError> error=>...}`. You'll have to wait for C# 9 and discriminated unions to implement a real Either

Comment: BTW what do you mean when you say the `Either` pattern? When I hear about it I think about F#, pattern matching and DIs.

Comment: I don't know if it's a pattern, but more like a common practice for error handling https://medium.com/techtron/functional-errors-handling-1d1b4688769d . I was just wondering if, given the fancy attributes we got, there was one able to say something along: it either returns this as not null, or this as not null. I suspect that if there was, it would probably be supported through a simple structure such as the struct in my question, with attributes at the right place.

Comment: You can call it a pattern or idiom. It's not just a common practice. A better reference would be [F#'s Result type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results) and Scott Wlaschin's [Railway-Oriented programming](https://swlaschin.gitbooks.io/fsharpforfunandprofit/content/posts/recipe-part2.html). Scott Wlaschin's article explains this far better than the articles that came after it

Comment: `Is there a way to do such a thing with the new attributes ?` No.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update for structs**

The code doesn't change when the result types change to structs. To use struct type parameters, the following constraints have to be added to the interface and the types:

```
where TResult : struct
where TError  : struct
```

---

When I think about the Either pattern, I think about F#, pattern matching and discriminated unions, not nulls. In fact, `Either` is a way to *avoid* nulls. In fact, the question's code looks like an attempt to create a [Result type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results), not just an Either. Scott Wlaschin's [Railway Oriented Programming](https://swlaschin.gitbooks.io/fsharpforfunandprofit/content/posts/recipe-part2.html) shows how such a type can be used to implement error handling in a functional language.

In F#, the [Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results) type is defined as:

```
type Result<'T,'TError> = 
    | Ok of ResultValue:'T 
    | Error of ErrorValue:'TError
```

We can't do that in C# 8 yet, because there are no discriminated unions. Those are planned for C# 9.

**Pattern Matching**

What we *can* do, is use pattern matching to get the same behavior eg:

```
interface IResult<TResult,TError>{} //No need for an actual implementation

public class Success<TResult,TError>:IResult<TResult,TError>

{
    public TResult Result {get;}

    public Success(TResult result) { Result=result;}
}

public class Error<TResult,TError>:IResult<TResult,TError>
{
    public TError ErrorValue {get;}

    public Error(TError error) { ErrorValue=error;}
}
```

This way there's no way to create an `IResult<>` that is both a success and error. This can be used with pattern matching, eg:

```
IResult<int,string> someResult=.....;

if(someResult is Success<int,string> s)
{
    //Use s.Result here
}
```

**Simplifying the expressions**

Given C# 8's [property patterns](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/), this could be rewritten as :

```
if(someResult is Success<int,string> {Result: var result} )
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

or, using switch expressions, a typical railway-style call :

```
IResult<int,string> DoubleIt(IResult<int,string> data)
{
    return data switch {    Error<int,string> e=>e,
                            Success<int,string> {Result: var result}=>
                                       new Success<int,string>(result*2),
                            _ => throw new Exception("Unexpected type!")
                            };
}
```

F# wouldn't need that `throw` as there's no way that an `Result<'T,'TError>` would be something other than `Ok` or `Error`. In C#, we don't have that feature *yet*.

The switch expression allows exhaustive matching. I think the compiler will generate a warning if the default clause is missing too.

**With deconstructors**

The expressions can be simplified a bit more if the types have deconstructors, eg:

```
public class Success<TResult,TError>:IResult<TResult,TError>
{
    public TResult Result {get;}

    public Success(TResult result) { Result=result;}

    public void Deconstruct(out TResult result) { result=Result;}
}

public class Error<TResult,TError>:IResult<TResult,TError>
{
    public TError ErrorValue {get;}

    public Error(TError error) { ErrorValue=error;}

    public void Deconstruct(out TError error) { error=ErrorValue;}
}
```

In that case the expression can be written as :

```
return data switch {    
                Error<int,string> e => e,
                Success<int,string> (var result) => new Success<int,string>(result*3),
                _ => throw new Exception("Unexpected type!")
};
```

**Nullability**

The question started with nullable reference types, so what about nullability? Will we get a warning in C# 8 if we try to pass a nulll?

Yes, as long as NRTs are enabled. This code :

```
#nullable enable

void Main()
{
     IResult<string,string> data=new Success<string,string>(null);
     var it=Append1(data);
     Console.WriteLine(it);
}

IResult<string,string> Append1(IResult<string,string> data)
{
    return data switch {    Error<string,string> e=>e,
                            Success<string,string> (var result)=>
                                new Success<string,string>(result+"1"),
                            _ => throw new Exception("Unexpected type!")
                            };
}
```

Genereates `CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type`

Trying

```
string? s=null;
IResult<string,string> data=new Success<string,string>(s);
```

Generates `CS8604: Possible null reference argument ....`

Answer (score 2):

When implementing `Either` monad, you should use two different constructors. That way, you can easily get away from those checks because your implementation will make sure that there is no way to have both properties assigned at the same time.

```
public readonly class Either<TReturn, TError>
{
    bool _successful;
    private TError _error { get; }
    private TReturn _response { get; }

    public Either(TError error)
    {
        _error = error;
    }

    public Either(TReturn response)
    {
       _successful = true;
       _response = response;
    }
}
```

Besides that, you need to add a method (to the struct) which will be used to extract the value from the struct, and transform it into common return type:

```
public Match<T>(Func<TError, T> errorFunc, Func<TResponse, T> successFunc)
    => _successful ? successFunc(_response) : errorFunc(_error);
```

That way, you are enforcing users to handle both cases (success, error) and provide functions which will do transformation into common type:

```
var errorEither = new Either<string, int>(10); // example of error code
var successEither = new Either<string, int>("success"); // example of success

var commonValueError = errorEither.Match<bool>(err => false, succ => true);
var commonValueSuccess = successEither.Match<bool>(err => false, succ => true);
```

Comment: C# already has pattern matching and this is a question about C# 8. Nulls weren't needed even in C# 7

Comment: It's not about pattern matching, and the shown implementation is wrong, so isn't it better to provide correct one - which will completely circumvent the issue with nullable types? Otherwise it doesn't make sense to use Either monad...

Comment: It does make sense. In fact, the question's code is a [Result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results), something so useful that Rust and F# offer a built-in type for it. As for pattern matching, it eliminates the need for that `Match` method

Comment: `Result` is nothing else than the `Either` (e.g. Haskell calls it like that) - so we are talking about same thing. Even if pattern matching is the same as in F#, you still need to follow the requirements of the type. So, in order to extract values from such type, you need to pass functions to handle both cases (using pattern matching, or `Match` method, or whatever). That's why your implementation is wrong and I hope OP will not follow it.

Comment: This isn't Haskell, it's .NET Core. There's already a functional language implementing Either and Result, that's F#. Those types are already used in multiple libraries. As I already explaine multiple times there's no way that Either can be implemented **yet**, because discriminated unions aren't available *yet*.

Comment: Of course it can be, I just showed you :D. However having discriminated unions or pattern matching in place would make implementation/usage trivial... That's the only difference/downside of the C# at the moment.

Comment: In fact I can claim that this implementation is obviously wrong too as it violates OO principles by including useless fields. The class can't use *both* fields at the same time. There's a nullability issue too since we're talking about C# 8- what do those fields contain? WIll that class generate nullability warnings because the fields are nullable? (It will)'

Comment: Didn't know about "Useful fields" OO principle

Comment: You know it's a mistake for a type to have fields it can't use, just so some other type can access them. You know that type-driven design's aim is to make it *impossible* for an invalid state to exist at compile time. The only way to make this Either implementation safe is to add a runtime check

Comment: I think you are mixing things, if you don't want to have null values (avoud NRE), you should use Maybe<T> instead

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with Resharper `ContractAnnotation`. It's not C# 8 specific, (but... I don't think your example is really using nullable reference types anyway, is it? You are using nullable structs.)

```
[ContractAnnotation(
   "=> pError: null, pResponse: notnull; => pError: notnull, pResponse: null"
)]
public void Get(out TError? pError, out TReturn? pResponse) {
   pError = Error;
   pResponse = Response;
}
```

(The meaning of the string is that left of the `=>` is input conditions, and right of the `=>` is output conditions, with `;` separating different cases, and an unlabled value referring to the method return value. So in this case: regardless of input, the output condition is ether of null/notnull or notnull/null.)

Then use C# 7 feature `out var`:

```
GetAnEitherFromSomewhere()
.Get(out var error, out var response);
if (error != null) {
   // handle error
   return;
}

// response is now known to be not null, because we can only get here if error was null
```

Honestly I'm finding JetBrains's annotations `[NotNull]`, `[CanBeNull]`, and `[ContractAnnotation]` to be a lot more flexible (though more verbose) than nullable reference types. Basically they allow for the intermediate case, where there are situations where the value can be `null`, but also situations where the value cannot be `null`, and those situations are distinguishable at run-time. With nullable reference types, I can't specify the in-between case, I have to choose either definitely nullable or definitely not nullable.

Even something common like `TryParse`:

```
// should the result be nullable with nullable reference types on?
// you have to either lie with ! or else use ? and assume it can always be null
public bool TryParse(string pString, out SomeClass pResult) {
   if (<cant parse>) {
      pResult = null;
      return false;
   }

   pResult = value;
   return true;
}

// works great with JetBrains annotations and nullable reference types off
// now you can know that the result is null or notnull
// based on testing the bool return value
[ContractAnnotation("=> true, pResult: notnull; => false, pResult: null")]
public bool TryParse(string pString, out SomeClass pResult) {
   ...
}
```